# Delete JSON content before presenting data to the user / remove JavaScript object properties

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs

I have a problem and I'm not quite sure why I can't resolve my issue.

I have a SPA that is built using AngularJS, Node.JS and MongoDB (Mongoose). Now on the client I have a form to register a new user. The form has a text input that has a function associated with its `onblur` event (or `ng-blur` to be exact). The function sends a `Ajax/$http` call to the back end to check if the username is unique before the form is submitted. All works well, here is my code thus far (please note that I have slightly modified the code for this question)...

Here's the text box,

```
<input type="text" name="displayName" id="displayName" ng-model="user.displayName" ng-blur="checkUserName(user)" />
```

here's the blur function in my controller

```
this.userNameCheck = function(user){
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/users/displayName/' + user.displayName})
            .then(function(response) {
               if(response.data.length > 0){
                   user.userWarning = userWarning; // userWarning is a string/ var that is passed to the form
               }

            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
    };
```

and here is my Node/mongoose code that is contained within a different project:

```
exports.displayName = function (req, res, next, displayName) {

    User.find({displayName : displayName}).limit(1).exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!results) return next(new Error('No user found'));
        res.jsonp(results || null);
    });

};
```

all this great however when I check in the console I can see that when we have a match the returned results object contains everything like hashed password, salt, etc, etc... I'd like to prevent these from being returned in my object. So I amended my backend code thus:

```
exports.displayName = function (req, res, next, displayName) {

    User.find({displayName : displayName}).limit(1).exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!results) return next(new Error('No user found'));

        // new code
        if(results.length !== 0){
            var returnObj =  results[0];
             delete returnObj.hashed_password;
             delete returnObj.salt;
             delete returnObj._id;
            res.jsonp([returnObj] || null)
        }else{
            res.jsonp(results || null);
        }
    });

};
```

Now when checking in Firebug what is returned with a successful call (a match has been found) the returned object still contains the deleted properties... where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can't help with the actual problem, but note that the `null` part of `res.jsonp([returnObj] || null)` will never be used. That line equates to `res.jsonp([returnObj])`. Arrays are never falsey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the return object has those properties further up the prototype chain and so they don't actually get deleted.

> If the delete operator succeeds, it removes the property from the object entirely. However, if a property with the same name exists on the object's prototype chain, the object will inherit that property from the prototype.

~ MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

You could check for this with `hasOwnProperty` to test this theory, but it may be safer just to build an on the fly object of the values that you want, or to restrict the values returned from Mongo?

In other words, on-the-fly with JavaScript (something like) :

```
var returnObj =  results[0],
safeUserObj = {
   userName : returnObj["username"],
   email : returnObj["email"]
};

res.jsonp([safeUserObj]);
```

Or you could return only the fields you want from Mongo, using the aggregation framework's `$match` and `$project`.  (console style code below, not sure how you'd need to adapt this for Mongoose)

```
db.users.aggregate([
{ $match : { displayName : displayName } },
{ $project : {
    displayName : 1,
    email : 1
  }
}
]);
```

EDIT : to mention that you could use the project parameter of find to do the same as I did in the bottom solution without using the aggregation framework.

Comment: I've decided to create a new object on the fly to be sure and I'm running against the clock!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to delete from the Mongoose object, rather than the actual storage. The simplest change would be to:

```
 var returnObj =  results[0].toJSON();
 delete returnObj.hashed_password;
 delete returnObj.salt;
 delete returnObj._id;
```

You could also just `select` ([documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)) the fields you want to include/exclude.

Comment: +1. also the direct call to `delete returnObj._doc.hashed_password;` should work too in this particular case with mongoose object. tested.